# Fold current screen onFling or on swipe up down in some app....How to develop like that any idea?

Tags: android

Fold current screen onFling or on Swipe up down in some app....How to develop like that any idea??

[image]

onFling the page fold like below image....

Comment: see this link this has all types of animation implementation. https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui

Comment: Thank man.this link is very nice and helpful....